Why do different users of SSRS 2022 see different data sources for the same report in Report Builder?
I have a report in SSRS (SQL Server v2022) that isn't displaying data. When I open the report in Report Builder and look at the only data source, I see this:

When one coworker opens the same report, he only sees one available shared connection, and its IP ends with 14 (correct) whereas mine ends with 8 (selected, incorrect). When a different coworker opens the same report, he sees many available shared connections, but the selected one is different than the other two, and is incorrect.
How can this happen when we're all looking at the same report?
Also, when I change the data source to the correct one, test the connection successfully, and close the dialog, when I reopen it, it's got the original, incorrect connection selected.
I have tried:

Selecting the correct connection in the dialog, closing the dialog, and reopening it.
Saving the report to my local disc, closing Report Builder, reopening the .rdl file, and selecting the correct connection.
Changing the connection to the correct one, then saving it locally, close, and reopen.
Changing the connection to the correct one and saving it back to SSRS.

After all of these, the original (incorrect) data source connection remains selected and produces no results.

datasource permissions on the server?
